# ¿Por qué no inicia sesión mi aplicación JSP?

Tags: java, sql, glassfish

Estoy haciendo un inicio de sesión básico con JSP y MySQL. Tengo un problema y es que no puedo iniciar sesión. Es más, cuando presiono el botón de inicio de sesión no pasa nada y necesito que me redirija a la página `menu.jsp`.

Aquí el `index.jsp`:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Iniciar Sesion</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Iniciar Sesion</h1>
        <from action="iniciar" method="post">
            <label>Nombre</lable>
            <input type="text" name="usuario" /><br>
            <label>Contraseña</lable>
            <input type="password" name="pass" /><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesion"/>
        </from>
        <br>
        No tienes cuenta... <a href="registro.jsp">Registrarme</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Este es el servlet:

```
package Servlet;

import Controlador.Consultas;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 */
public class InicioSesion extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
        String contraseña = request.getParameter("pass");

        Consultas co = new Consultas();
        if(co.autenticacion(usuario, contraseña)){
            response.sendRedirect("menu.jsp");
        }else{
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }

    }
}
```

Estoy trabajando en Netbeans con Java, PhpmyAdmin y Glassfish server.
¿Alguna solución? Gracias.

Comment: Prueba con **getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, res);**

Comment: Tienes un error tipográfico en la etiqueta `<form>...</form>`, has puesto `<from>...</from>`. Además, ¿es correcta la URL del `action`? Has puesto `action="iniciar"` y es probable que quisieras poner `action="iniciar.jsp"`.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes mal la etiqueta del formulario, has puesto `from` en vez de `form`

Aquí lo tienes corregido

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Iniciar Sesion</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Iniciar Sesion</h1>
        <form action="iniciar" method="post">
            <label>Nombre</lable>
            <input type="text" name="usuario" /><br>
            <label>Contraseña</lable>
            <input type="password" name="pass" /><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesion"/>
        </form >
        <br>
        No tienes cuenta... <a href="registro.jsp">Registrarme</a>

    </body>
</html>
```